# App crashes on higher versions of android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

I have been creating an app, built on target sdk version 15 and with minimum sdk version of 8. Every thing is running perfect when I run it on a devices running version 8. But when I try it on anything higher than version 10 it crashes with a NullPointerException.

The logcat gives me this:

```
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start                 activity        ComponentInfo{com.fansheroid.facts.chicks/com.fansheroid.facts.chicks.MainActivity}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.fansheroid.facts.chicks.MainActivity.getTumblrs(MainActivity.java:156)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.fansheroid.facts.chicks.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
10-06 19:23:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  ... 11 more
```

I have been trying to figure out the problem for the past two days, but it just doesn't make sense for me.

EDIT ADDED CODE

```
public ArrayList<Tumblr> getTumblrs() throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException, JSONException {
    String searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY";

    ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs = new ArrayList<Tumblr>();

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    String responseBody = null;
    try {
        responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

    JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray(
            "posts");
    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("photos");
        for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j);
            String url = photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes").getJSONObject(0)
                    .getString("url");

            Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url);
            tumblrs.add(tumblr);
        }
    }
    return tumblrs;
}
```

Line 156:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
```

Comment: Please show line 156 of MainActivity.java, and the surrounding method, as well as any methods relating to that. (And earmark 156, please.)

Comment: There might be something about the `ResponseHandler` class not working on newer APIs. Try using the `HttpResponse` and `HttpEntity` classes to get the body.

Comment: It is already in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using HttpResponse and HttpEntity instead of ResponseHandler, and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, look at this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(589): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 10-06 19:23:12.927: 
E/AndroidRuntime(589): at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116) 10-06 19:23:12.927:
E/AndroidRuntime(589): at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94) 10-06 19:23:12.927:
E/AndroidRuntime(589): at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:154) 10-06 19:23:12.927: 
E/AndroidRuntime(589): at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:171) 10-06 19:23:12.927: 
E/AndroidRuntime(589): at com.fansheroid.facts.chicks.MainActivity.getTumblrs(MainActivity.java:156) 10-06 19:23:12.927: 
E/AndroidRuntime(589): at com.fansheroid.facts.chicks.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
```

It basically says the JSON parser fails: you're probably passing NULL on line 156 of MainActivity.java. You should check the value at that line and see if your device upgrade hasn't somehow wiped out a value or failed to retrieve a value correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but i still can't find the problem. I have added some of the code, can you try to help a little further?

Comment: He told you to check line 156. Make sure to mark in the code which line is 156.

Comment: The last line i my question clearly specifies which line line 156 is.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

That section of code is where your response is failing. You assign null to responsebody, chances are that your call there is failing so that responsebody is still null when it hits line 156.

Try looking in your debug output for the ex.printStackTrace(); output to see what is going on.

Comment: How could i get around this problem then?

Comment: Well this line is your problem:  responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler); Figure out why client.execute isn't putting data into responseBody. Maybe responseHandler is malformed.